# Howto update entity field automatically when some entity date field is in past compared to current date?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I have a table with the following fields:

```
@Entity
public class TableA{
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    private String status;

    public TableA() {
    }
    //Setter and getter methods
}
```

The date field states the expiry date/time for this entry and when current date/time reaches the stated expiry date the status should be updated as "Expired".

Is there a refined way of setting this expiry instead of me using a periodic timer to check through all the records?

I'm using JpaRepository and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no means for automagical update on behalf of `JPA` or other technologies than polling and updating. However, your status should be method that calculates the status (instead of field) like:

```
public String getStatus() {
    if(date.before(new Date())) return "expired";
    return ""; // or what ever are statuses
}
```

Furthermore you should collect statuses as `enum` values.

With `JPA` you could of course use `@PrePersist` & `@PostLoad` when fetching or storing to db, like:

```
@PrePersist // benefit of this would be marginal since usually you do not deal 
            // much with entity after persisting
@PostLoad
private void updateStatus() {
    if(date.before(new Date())) status = "expired";
```

The problem with above approach would be that those updates above are triggered only when persisting or loading entity. So if you would have loaded a non-expired entity and it would expire during session you would not notice it expired until persisting 1st time after it has expired.

Comment: With the first example you mentioned, when exactly is getStatus() called? I'm asking so that i can better predict when will the status actually be "updated/checked" since the checking is done inside the getStatus() method.

Comment: @Cherple That method should be called explicitly whenever you need to know the status. So like you would query for the field status but instead of providing getter to return field named _status_ you create method to calculate the status every time that method is called.

Comment: I see.. So technically for what i wish to achieve it's still pretty much manual checking. I understand, was just trying to see if there's some sort of automation available which i don't know of haha.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You actually can calculate this status when you select your data from db:

```
SELECT date < NOW() as status FROM TableA;
```

Or create cron job in your code or database to do that from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE EVENT updateEvent
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 3 HOUR
        DO
update TableA 
set status='Expired' 
where date < date_sub(now(),interval 24 hour);
```

You can create database event in order to update status in every 3 hour by this event.